# Looping in jinja

Tags: python, django, loops, jinja2

I have a Integer value inside {{ review.rating }} . Now I want to loop using jinja , the number of times the value of review.rating.

Eg. if I have review.rating = 4 , I want to display `<div>A</div>` , 4 times.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 4):

You can use for loop in jinja like this:

```
{% for i in range(review.rating) %}
<span>{{ i }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried this , but it gives this error , 
Could not parse the remainder: '(review.rating)' from 'range(review.rating)'

Comment: Could not parse the remainder: '(4)' from 'range(4)' , i tried this also , but i dont know why its not taking anything

Comment: can you share your error log in comment? @ManasManSingh